# How to create a fragment without extending Fragment android

Tags: android, android-fragments

The problem i am having is that my 2 fragments need to extend the Fragment class so i can use them as fragments. But these 2 classes are already extending a class..

How can i use them as fragments?

```
public class Result_Main extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.result_main);

        final ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));


    }

    private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            switch (pos) {
                case 0:
                    return new Result_Primary(); 
                case 1:
                    return new Result_Additional();
                default:
                    return new Result_Primary();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Let your base class extending the Fragment then. But it is not advisable to have all logic in fragment. You should have Fragment contains your logic class instead as presenter. Do read out the MVP pattern in Android.

Comment: which class extended, a predefined java or android class or self made class to your actvity.

Comment: they extend a self made class which is vital to my application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we Know that Java doesn't support multiple inheritance. So you can't extend multiple class with a class.

You can follow two approach to solve your problem.

1. As you said you are extending two class one is Fragment and second is self made class. So you can implement a interface like...

`interface A extends selfmade class`

and implement interface A to your main Class

```
class Main extends Fragment implements A
```

2. you can also make self made(extending) class as a private inner class in your main class.(if your extending class is not using in other class)

Hope this will help you.